# Google Dialogflow CX tutorial

Tags: dialogflow-cx

I am getting stuck on the tutorial for dialogflox CX.  I am beginner.

https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/cx/docs/quick/build-agent (link to tutorial)

I am getting stuck at trying to setup the conditions correctly. where if 1 condition is not met then the agent should ask user to specify the incomplete parameter.

the chatbot goes from "Lets take your order" to "Order is confirmed".  So for example, if I say i want a blue shirt the agent will not take any action when it should be requesting additional information like size of shirt as 2 parameters must be met such as size of shirt and color of shirt.

If i ask agent to order a large blue shirt then the agent goes to the order confirmation.

If someone can elaborate further how i need to go about this.  Below is the part from the tutorial I am getting lost

[image]

Here is the test agent.  It is missing the part where when I say blue shirt then it should ask for more information.

[image]

Comment: Hi @VBA Noob,I have posted an answer. I hope it will help you. Do consider upvoting and accepting if it helps, otherwise let me know so that I can improve my answer. Take a look at this [example](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Sa85lRuCEIs&t=632s) also.

Answer (score 0):

You can consider the form filling option in dialogflow cx for your requirement. According to the official [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/cx/docs/concept/parameter#form) for each page, you can define a form, which is a list of parameters that should be collected from the end-user for the page. The agent interacts with the end-user for multiple conversation turns, until it has collected all of the required form parameters, which are also known as page parameters. The agent collects these parameters in the order defined on the page. For each required form parameter, you also provide prompts that the agent uses to request that information from the end-user.